# How to select by CSS styles in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to find all the parent elements that have the CSS style `display:none`. I can't seem to get it to work though. Here's what I've got:

```
var $parents = $(...).parents("[css=display:none]");
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want the ones that are *actually* `display: none;` (not just possibly *contained* in another `display: none;`), you can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to get those parents, like this:

```
var $parents = $(...).parents().filter(function() {
                  return $(this).css('display') == 'none';
               });
```

This gets the parents, then filters them to get only the ones that are `display: none;` on *that* specific parent.

Answer (score 9):

[@Nick's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640061/jquery-selector-how-to-select-by-css-styles/3640078#3640078) is a very simple and straightforward method of achieving your goal.  It's also probably the best performing method.  However, for the sake of completeness and convenience (if you're doing this a lot), it's also possible to create your own selector:

```
$.expr[':'].css = function(obj, index, meta, stack) {
    var args = meta[3].split(/\s*=\s*/);
    return $(obj).css(args[0]) == args[1];
}

// Then we can use our custom selector, like so:
$("#myElement").parents(":css(display=none)").show();
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/V8CQr/.

See more information on creating custom selectors at:

http://www.jameswiseman.com/blog/2010/04/19/creating-a-jquery-custom-selector/

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('a').parents('div[style*="display: none"], [style*="display:none"]').show();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Test" style="color: Red; display: none;">
        aaa <a href="#test">test</a><br />
    </div>
    <div class="Test" style="color: Aqua;">
        bbb <a href="#test">test</a><br />
    </div>
    <div class="Test" style="font-size: 15px; display: none;">
        ccc <a href="#test">test</a><br />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close:

```
$(...).parents('[style*="display: none"]');
```

Note: this does a substring search on element attribute values so it's not as good as the `$(this).css(...)` filter solution shown above.

The [docs](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).