# How to grab the element with certain CSS property value inline

Tags: javascript, css

I am a newbie to Js. 
I am trying to grab the element from an image array where the `opacity` of the image is set to `1`. Please tell me how is it possible.
I tried `hasAttribute` but I do not know how to compare with `==1`, as it gave unexpected results.

```
   <ul id="fullscreenImagesList">
        <li><span class="fullscrnImgs"></span></li>
       <li> <span class="fullscrnImgs" style="opacity: 1;"></span> </li>
        <li><span class="fullscrnImgs"></span></li>
        <li><span class="fullscrnImgs"></span> </li>
        <li><span class="fullscrnImgs"></span> </li>
    </ul>
```

And now the Js

```
var bigImages = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("fullscrnImgs"));
for (var i = 0; i < bigImages.length; i++) {

        var opac = bigImages[i].getAttribute("opacity");
        console.log(opac);    

    }
```

Comment: are you using jQuery?

Comment: are you sure its an attribute and not a css style?

Comment: Depending on your code [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3640078/1124565) may help, but you may be able to achieve the same thing more efficiently but we can't be sure without your code. So please post your code

Comment: You may want to use `console.log(some_value)` to see what you get...

Comment: `opacity` is not an attribute. It's a CSS property. When you say "image array", do you mean an array of HTML `<img>` elements?

Comment: no no juery just plain javascript..

Comment: Very puzzled why you would edit your question to include JS which uses `getAttribute`, when from the comments and answers you had already received prior to the edit, you should be aware that `opacity` is **NOT** an *attribute*, but rather a *CSS property*, which are two very different things, and must be retrieved in very different ways. (As a minor aside, there is no need to do all the `[].slice.call` stuff if all you are going to do is loop over the nodelist with a `for` statement.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking for a `opacity` property in the in-line style attribute on the element, as shown in your example, then

```
bigImages[i].style.opacity
```

will do the trick.

The entire solution is

```
var bigImages = document.getElementsByClassName("fullscrnImgs");
for (var i = 0; i < bigImages.length; i++) {
    var opac = bigImages[i].style.opacity;
    console.log(opac);    
}
```

However, actually `opacity` is a CSS property which could be set in many ways; in addition to being an in-line style attribute on the element, it could be set via the CSS cascade. The only reliable way to check the actual opacity in effect on the element is with `getComputedStyle`:

```
var opac = window.ComputedStyle(bigImages[i]).opacity;
```

Comment: Check my answer again. It shows clearly how to get the opacity value for an element.

Answer (score 0):

with jquery:

```
var image= $('img[opacity="1"]');
```

Comment: Is `jQuery` tagged in question ?

Comment: But `opacity` is a CSS property, not an attribute that you could address with this kind of selector.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using an element, you should use the getAttribute method

```
var opac = imageElement.getAttribute("opacity");
```

[EDIT]
Be sure to check to see if the variable is defined. Something like this would do

```
if (typeof opac === 'undefined') {
    //opac is defined
}
```

[EDIT 2]
If you are looking for the css style, use [window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(imageElement);
var opacity = style.getPropertyValue("opacity");
```

Comment: You may want to explain how to determine whether the attribute is defined?

Comment: But it's not an attribute, it's a CSS property.

Comment: If an attribute is not present, then `getAttribute` will return `null`, not `undefined`. Although all of that is irrelevant, since `opacity` is not an attribute that can be retrieved with `getAttribute` anyway.